# how change the value of input type time and date in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, datepicker, jsx

I have two input and I want put a init value for example the user time.

```
  <input type="time" id="horaFinal" ref={(hora_final) => this.hora_final = hora_final} />
  <input type="date" id="fechaFinal" ref={(fecha_final) => this.fecha_final = fecha_final} />
```

I can take the value with this code `var yearInit = this.fecha_inicial.value`

but I cant put the init value, I try with `this.fecha_inicial.value= 01/02/2017`in the componentWillMout, componentDidMount,constructor, but not working

Comment: are you trying to add a default value (`defaultValue={yearInit}`)?

Comment: or `value={ this.props.value ? this.props.value : 'default value' }`?

Comment: Use the `value` prop to pass down a value to the underlying component (be it native html elements, they're still transpiled to react components by the JSX)
Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props

Comment: oohh thanks, its working now